# PinnedHeaderListView Example

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to implement a listview with section headers similar to the one found in android mobile contacts, in which the section headers do not scroll while scrolling the contents inside the header.
I found out that something like a PinnedHeaderListView has to be implemented.
Does anybody have ant example on how to develop a PinnedHeaderListView ?

Comment: http://blog.peterkuterna.net/2011/05/pinned-header-listview-as-in-contacts.html i found some samples as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this Project using SVN from this link [PinnedHeaderListView](http://code.google.com/p/devoxx2010/source/checkout)

You will get sample App , inside that Click on **Speakers** there you can see PinnedHeaderListView same as that of in iPhone..

Also refer this [Link](http://blog.peterkuterna.net/2011/05/pinned-header-listview-as-in-contacts.html)

Comment: Thank you for the link.It uses a Cursor Adapter. Can i get an example that does not use a cursor adapter?

Comment: @kirtipriya Just customize the Adapter according to your needs!

Comment: refer link was broken

Comment: The peterkuterna.net link is broken.