# ListView in Android as like in IOS

Tags: android

I'm looking for way to create list view as like in IOS with pinned headers. is there a way to do this ? Thanks for the help in advance of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an Answer. [Android Amazing List View](http://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/)

[How to draw a section header in android listview just like the ios's UITableview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943802/how-to-draw-a-section-header-in-android-listview-just-like-the-ioss-uitableview)

Answer (score 1):

You can do SVN checkout for [Pinned Sectioned ListView same as iPhone](http://code.google.com/p/android-playground/source/checkout) from this link.. Hope you are looking for this Sample..