# Navigation Drawer with Headers/Sections

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, navigation-drawer

I would like to know if there is any way that I can add headers/sections to the navigation drawer. I managed to add something like that, but it is only displayed at the top of the list, because addHeaderView needs to be called before setAdapter and if I try to add more elements after setAdapter they will rewrite the first elements.

Thanks.

Edit:

```
public class MenuListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

// Declare Variables
Context context;
String[] mTitle;
String[] mSubTitle;
int[] mIcon;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public MenuListAdapter(Context context, String[] title, String[] subtitle,
        int[] icon) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mTitle = title;
    this.mSubTitle = subtitle;
    this.mIcon = icon;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return super.getViewTypeCount();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mTitle.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mTitle[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Declare Variables
    TextView txtTitle;
    TextView txtSubTitle;
    ImageView imgIcon;

    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, parent,
            false);

    // Locate the TextViews in drawer_list_item.xml
    txtTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    txtSubTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);

    // Locate the ImageView in drawer_list_item.xml
    imgIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

    // Set the results into TextViews
    txtTitle.setText(mTitle[position]);
    txtSubTitle.setText(mSubTitle[position]);

    // Set the results into ImageView
    imgIcon.setImageResource(mIcon[position]);

    return itemView;
}
```

}

EDIT:

I found a good solution by combining solutions from different sources, this are the main classes that I used:

**EntryAdapter**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.androidbegin.sidemenututorial.R;

public class EntryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    private enum RowType {
        LIST_ITEM, HEADER_ITEM
    }

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Item> items;
    private LayoutInflater vi;

    public EntryAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> items) {
        super(context,0, items);
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
        vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {  //Returns the number of types of Views that will be created by getView(int, View, ViewGroup).
        return RowType.values().length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) { //framework calls getItemViewType for row n, the row it is about to display.
        //Get the type of View that will be created by getView(int, View, ViewGroup) for the specified item.
        Log.i("LIST", "item at " + position + " is " 
                + ((getItem(position).isSection() ? 0 : 1) == 0 ? "section" : "normal item"));
        return getItem(position).isSection() ? 0 : 1; // get position passes (n) and accertain  is its a header  or not
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return !getItem(position).isSection();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        final Item i = items.get(position);
        if (i != null) {
            if(i.isSection()){
                SectionItem si = (SectionItem) i;
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_section, null);

                v.setOnClickListener(null);
                v.setOnLongClickListener(null);
                v.setLongClickable(false);

                final TextView sectionView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_section_text);
                sectionView.setText(si.getTitle());
            }else{
                EntryItem ei = (EntryItem) i;
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_entry, null);
                final TextView title = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_title);
                final TextView subtitle = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_summary);

                if (title != null) 
                    title.setText(ei.title);
                if(subtitle != null)
                    subtitle.setText(ei.subtitle);
            }
        }
        return v;
    }

}
```

**EntryItem**

```
public class EntryItem implements Item{

    public final String title;
    public final String subtitle;

    public EntryItem(String title, String subtitle) {
        this.title = title;
        this.subtitle = subtitle;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSection() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

**Item**

```
public interface Item {

    public boolean isSection();

}
```

**SectionItem**

```
public class SectionItem implements Item{

    private final String title;

    public SectionItem(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSection() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

**MainActivity**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.androidbegin.item.EntryAdapter;
import com.androidbegin.item.EntryItem;
import com.androidbegin.item.Item;
import com.androidbegin.item.SectionItem;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    // Declare Variable
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    ListView mDrawerList;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    MenuListAdapter mMenuAdapter;
    String[] title;
    String[] subtitle;
    int[] icon;
    Fragment fragment1 = new Fragment1();
    Fragment fragment2 = new Fragment2();
    Fragment fragment3 = new Fragment3();
    Context context;

    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.drawer_main);
        this.context = this;
        // Generate title
        title = new String[] { "Title Fragment 1", "Title Fragment 2",
                "Title Fragment 3" };

        // Generate subtitle
        subtitle = new String[] { "Subtitle Fragment 1", "Subtitle Fragment 2",
                "Subtitle Fragment 3" };

        // Generate icon
        icon = new int[] { R.drawable.action_about, R.drawable.action_settings,
                R.drawable.collections_cloud };

        // Locate DrawerLayout in drawer_main.xml
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        // Locate ListView in drawer_main.xml
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // Set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
        // opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                GravityCompat.START);

        // Pass results to MenuListAdapter Class
//      mMenuAdapter = new MenuListAdapter(this, title, subtitle, icon);

        // Set the MenuListAdapter to the ListView
//      mDrawerList.setAdapter(mMenuAdapter);

        items.add(new SectionItem("Category 1"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Item 1", "This is item 1.1"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Item 2", "This is item 1.2"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Item 3", "This is item 1.3"));


        items.add(new SectionItem("Category 2"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Item 4", "This is item 2.1"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Item 5", "This is item 2.2"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Item 6", "This is item 2.3"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Item 7", "This is item 2.4"));

        items.add(new SectionItem("Category 3"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Item 8", "This is item 3.1"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Item 9", "This is item 3.2"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Item 10", "This is item 3.3"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Item 11", "This is item 3.4"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Item 12", "This is item 3.5"));

        EntryAdapter adapter = new EntryAdapter(this, items);

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Capture button clicks on side menu
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // Enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close) {

            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {

            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
            }
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // The click listener for ListView in the navigation drawer
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            Log.i("LIST", "item position = " + Integer.toString(position)
                    + "\nitem id = " + String.valueOf(id));
            if (!items.get(position).isSection()) {
                EntryItem item = (EntryItem)items.get(position);

                Toast.makeText(context, "You clicked " + item.title , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                selectItem(position);
            }
//          selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {

        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        // Locate Position
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment1);
                break;
            case 1:
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment2);
                break;
            case 2:
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment3);
                break;
        }
        ft.commit();
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        // Close drawer
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

But I have a little problem: the sections take a position in the list and the selection of fragments is messed up.

Answer (score 6):

You add headers/sections to a `ListView` for use in a `DrawerLayout` the same way that you add headers/sections to a `ListView` for use anywhere else inside of Android.

At the low level, this involves a `ListAdapter` that:

- Overrides `getViewTypeCount()` to indicate how many distinct types of rows there are (e.g., 2, one for headers and one for regular rows)
- Overrides `getItemViewType()` to indicate which row type to use for a given `position`
- Ensures that `getView()` (or `newView()`/`bindView()` of a `CursorAdapter`) is aware of the multiple row types and processes them accordingly

At a higher level, you can try to use things like [my `MergeAdapter`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge), or various other third-party libraries, to help simplify this.

Comment: Thank you, I will try your library, although it seems a lot of work for something that feels it should be as default there.
If you know of other tutorials of how this can be achieved I will be much grateful.

Comment: @IonutNegru: A simple search on `android listview section headers` in your favorite search engine will turn up many pages, including libraries (such as http://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/), StackOverflow questions (such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943802/how-to-draw-a-section-header-in-android-listview-just-like-the-ioss-uitableview), tutorials/recipes (such as http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=992) and more.

Answer (score 1):

In the Navigation Drawer the item list can be displayed using a ListView so you can have a class adapter and implements your logic.
So you can add sections, headers and so on.

Comment: And how can I achieve that ? I already have an BaseAdapter that populates the list (because I added image and subtitle for the list) ?

I have added the Adapter in the main post.

Comment: Just implement a custom adapter and override the methods like getView and so on.

Comment: As you can see I already do that, but how do you recommend to add headers to the list of the navigation drawer ?

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a [complete example](http://www.michenux.net/android-navigation-drawer-748.html) of Navigation Drawer using headers/sections

This is the result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your list items are fixed(non-changing), a quick "hack" would be to include a switch case for "position" in your adapter's getView() method and inflate a headerlayout.xml at those fixed positions. Your regular inflation will go into the default part of switch case. It's dirty and not recommended but effective.

Comment: I would like to avoid this kind of hack because it will be difficult to be modified in the future(if it will be required). But thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest extending `EntryItem` by adding a tag member that tells you what type of fragment to create.  Then just check the tag in your `onItemClick` handler to create the correct type of fragment.  This way you're not dependent upon the position, which can change as you add/remove items in the sections.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to the EntryAdapter class:

```
@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled () {
    return false;
}
```

with that, and:

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return !getItem(position).isSection();
}
```

Sections shouldn't take a position on the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

A good solution I read was to place a header TextView inside your row layout file and set its visibility to `GONE`.

Then in your adapter's `getView`, have some logic that says:  Is this the very first item in the list (position 0), OR is the type of this item different than the type one position above it?  If so, turn the header `TextView's` visibility to `VISIBLE`.

This way is preferred because when you want to use `getItemAtPosition`, you don't have to figure out how to dodge your section headers as they would be taking up an entire position if you implemented them the way the OP and others suggested.