# list view inside list view inside list view

Tags: android, listview

I am new to android, I am creating app for movie show details. I need help in creating GUI for
I have list of different movies,
for each movie I have different movie theaters (list view)
And if theater is clicked I am showing different show timing (list view)

Please help me which ViewGroup is better Listview or recycler view or ExpandedListview

Thanks a lot in advance
Here the images: 
[normal listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCSYO.png)
[image]

[Expanded Listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sii81.png)

[image]

Comment: Given the very definition of an `ExpandableListView`*, I'd say that's what you want.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943802/how-to-draw-a-section-header-in-android-listview-just-like-the-ioss-uitableview this helped me thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

there you require the exapndable list view like structure..then I think below link should help you...
http://umakantpatil.com/posts/android-listview-with-separate-headers-and-images-loading-from-remote-server

Its just uses header for separating the list. You can anyways remove those headers.